# which data structure in java can add key/value pair at constant time and maintain sorted by value?

Tags: java, hashmap

basically i'm looking for a best data structure in java which i can store  pairs and retrieve top N number of element by the value. i'd like to do this in O(n) time where n is number of entires in the data structure.

example input would be,

```
<"john", 32>
<"dave", 3>
<"brian", 15>
<"jenna", 23>
<"rachael", 41>
```

and if N=3, i should be able to return rachael, john, jenna if i wanted descending order.

if i use some kind of hashMap, insertion is fast, but retrieving them by order gets expensive.
if i use some data structure that keeps things ordered, then insertion becomes expensive while retrieving is cheaper. i was not able to find the best data structure that can do both very well and very fast.

any input is appreciated. thanks.

[updated]

let me ask the question in other way if that make it clearer.
i know i can insert  at constant time O(1) into hashMap.
now, how can i retrieve elements from sorted order by value in O(n) time where n=number of entires in the data structure? hope it makes sense.

Comment: Im not sure if i understood but you can use a TreeMap. `This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.`

Comment: and hashmap `This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sort, you have to give up constant O(1) time.

That is because unlike inserting an unsorted key / value pair, sorting will minimally require you to compare the new entry to something, and odds are to a number of somethings.  Once you have an algorithm that will require more time with more entries (due to more comparisons) you have overshot "constant" time.

If you can do better, then by all means, do so!  There is a Dijkstra prize awaiting for you, if not a Fields Medal to boot.

Don't dispair, you can still do the key part as a HashMap, and the sorting part with a Tree like implementation, that will give you O(log n).  TreeMap is probably what you desire.

--- Update to match your update ---

No, you cannot iterate over a hashmap in O(n) time.  To do so would assume that you had a list; but, that list would have to already be sorted.  With a raw HashMap, you would have to search the entire map for the next "lower" value.  Searching part of the map would not do, because the one element you didn't check would possibly be the correct value.

Now, there are some data structures that make a lot of trade offs which might get you closer.  If you want to roll your own, perhaps a custom Fibonacci heap can give you an amortized performance close to what you wish, but it cannot guarantee a worst-case performance.  In any case, some operations (like extract-min) will still require O(log n) performance.